# Jquery Autocomplete not supported by keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Autocomplete is not working for keyboard keys but it is working for mouse.i couldnot select item by arrow keys and enter key.
Here is my code. please suggest me any idea. and how to change my selected item background colour in input field?

```
    var triggered = false;
    var trigger = "@";
    jQuery(".inputbox").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {                
                    var term = request.term; 
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/home/friends?q="+term,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                              // alert(item.value);
                                return {
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name                            }
                            }));
                        }
                    });

                },
        search: function() {
            if (!triggered) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var text = this.value;
            var pos = text.lastIndexOf(trigger);

            this.value = text.substring(0, pos + trigger.length) +
                ui.item.value;

            triggered = false;

            return false;
        },
        focus: function() { return false; },
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        allowNewTags: false
    }).bind("keyup", function() {
        var text = this.value;
        var len = text.length;
        var last;
        var query;
        var index;

        if (triggered) {
            index = text.lastIndexOf(trigger);
            query = text.substring(index + trigger.length);
            $(this).autocomplete("search", query);
        }
        else if (len >= trigger.length) {
            last = text.substring(len - trigger.length);
            triggered = (last === trigger);
        }
    });
```

Comment: use typehead js , inbuit mechanism is given

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt. It have this feature implemented by default.